# Find second and third matching value in Excel

Tags: excel, match

I have a table with 35 columns. Values in the cells are only zeros and ones. I need to return header name of the column per each 1 in each row.

For example:
I have Header 1, Header 2, and Header 3.
Value under Header 1 is 0, under Header 2 is 1, and under Header 3 is 1.

I need Header 2 as output and Header 3.

First match is easy, I did it through combination of index match functions.

How do I extract 2-nd and 3-d match?

Thank you

Comment: is your output in individual cells, are they horizontal or vertical?  Or, is the output in one cell delimited?  Also, what version are you using?

Comment: Output should be indeed in individual cells. And I search for the match horizontally. I use 2013. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `INDEX`/`AGGREGATE` functions:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$J$1,1,AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($A2:$J2)/($A2:$J2=1)),COLUMN(A1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Took me whole day. It works wonders. Wow. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My solution, but not in one formula:
[image]
First, I print the Column Numbers of the Ones, then I perform an offset operation to obtain the headers.

The `IFERROR()` is optional, of course.

For multiple rows just change the layout:
[image]

- Cell K2: `=IF(A2=1;COLUMN(A2);"")`
- Cell U2: `=OFFSET($A$1;0; SMALL($K2:$T2;U$1)-1)`

Comment: I have a lot of rows, this will be pretty crazy to repeat for each. But thanks))

Answer (score 0):

I created some dummy data:

[image]

Then put my cursor anywhere in the table and used Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range. This opened the Power Query Editor.

I then used Add Column>General>Index Column>From 1 to add a 1-based index. I re-positioned that index to the far left. That's not necessary, but helpful for me.

Then I selected the index column and used Transform>Any Column>Unpivot Columns>Unpivot Other Columns. That gave me this:

[image]

I then filtered the Value column on 1, then right-clicked the Value column and selected Remove. That left me with this:

[image]

Then I used Home>Close & Load to put the data back into the workbook. The index is an indicator of which row the header was derived from.

Of course, as the source data changes, you would be able to right-click the result table and select "Refresh" to re-run the transformation.

[image]

Comment: Creative. But does not match my purpose unfortunately. I need it exactly per each row: header for first 1 and header for second 1.